# read and write files from dropbox using python

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to write a code (for my personal use) that will access a particular directory in my dropbox.

The code currently uses local folder in my machine, and also lives in my local machine.
The minimal code is:

```
$ cat sync.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3
import dropbox
#This part is not yet needed as my work is still local
client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient\
    ("<access_code>")
print(client.account_info())
with open("~/Dropbox/ToDo/greet.html", "r") as fin:
print(fin.read())
```

This works fine, but I have to be with my laptop on.
Can I put the code in dropbox itself and make it run every hour? (in my local machine I do it with cron)
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

No, Dropbox itself doesn't offer any sort of application hosting where you can run code like this remotely.